# My front tooth was rei-implanted after avulsion......?

Tags: dentistry

I fell in my bath tub a week ago and my front tooth literally came out. I went to the dentist and he re-implanted the tooth, put some kind of glue/sealant to hold it in place and told me he would see if my body rejects it or not. He gave me some steroids and penicillin for infection. Everything was fine the first week but by Monday this week, I noticed the re-implanted tooth slowly getting lower than my other upper front tooth. (they were originally the same level) Am I going to lose this tooth! I'm really scared! My appointment isn't until next Tuesday!

Comment: Call the dentist and ask.